# using isDigit to find charecters c++

Tags: c++, loops, char, decimal

Trying to figure how I can use isDigit to ignore every character except x, X, e, E within a string. As you can see below I'm doing duodecimal to decimal with x equal to 10 and e equal to 11 (not case sensitive). Having trouble with cin.ignore(). The output should be 36. The string duo should read in the 3 then 0 and negate the rest.

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

main() {
  using str_t = std::string::size_type;

  str_t idx = 0;
  int decValue = 0;

  string duo = "30-something";

  while (isspace(duo.at(idx)) && idx < duo.length()) {
    idx++;
  }

  for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < duo.length(); ++i) {
    decValue *= 12;

    if (isdigit(duo.at(i))) {
      decValue += duo.at(i) - '0';
    }

    else if (duo.at(i) == 'x' || duo.at(i) == 'X') {
      decValue += 10;
    }

    else if (duo.at(i) == 'e' || duo.at(i) == 'E') {
      decValue += 11;
    }
    /// Program works if this executable line is taken out
    else if (!char.isDigit(duo.at(i))) {
      cin.ignore();
    }
  }
  cout << decValue << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why `std::isdigit()` at all? If you only care about X and E, wouldn't it be simpler to just check if it's an X or an E? You could use `std::tolower()` or `std::toupper()` (dealer's choice) to simplify that check, even.

Comment: Why `ignore` at all? There is no other use of `cin`. All in all this is one confusing and confused question.

Comment: And if I'm understanding correctly, you're supposed to be converting a `std::string` from base-12 to base-10? How does that work? Base-12 would be 0-9 + AB, right?

Comment: Finally working my way to the commented line that is throwing an error, that's wildly bad syntax. What's the goal of that line, and why is it so different from your other checks? Copy/paste, perhaps?

Comment: Going back to the text of the question, you claim that the 3 should be read in and everything else negated, but you have `e` in your string, which you claim you don't want to ignore. So which is it?

Comment: The idea that it would just 36 seems way off, to boot. `decValue` will become 36 during the second iteration, but you continue to loop through the string, multiplying `decValue` by 12 every time. And why should it be 36, again? As has been said, the question is incredibly unclear.

Comment: `char.isDigit` isn’t legal. `char` is an integer type. It doesn’t have member functions.

Comment: @sweenish — 30 base 12 is 36 base 10.

Comment: @PeteBecker But what does "30-something" base-12 translate to? It should translate to an exception. That would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Below I modified your code so that it gives correct answer. For input `30-something` it gives `36` as output.

As I understood you want to finish conversion right after `30` i.e. ignore `-something`. For such behaviour I put a flag `stop_on_first_non_digit` in my code, if it is `true` then it finishes on first non-digit character. But you may set it to `false` then I just skip non-digit chars but use all chars that are digits, for example `-something` has `e` in it, so contains one digit, if `stop_on_first_non_digit` is `false` then this single `e` digit will be used. By default now it is `true` so that it behaves the way you like.

Also I kept your logic of skipping first spaces in a string so you can input       `30-something` (leading spaces) and it gives `36` too.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/ehxaozT3c)

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string duo = "30-something";
    bool stop_on_first_non_digit = true;
    size_t i = 0;
    int decValue = 0;

    while (i < duo.length() && std::isspace(duo.at(i)))
        ++i;

    for (; i < duo.length(); ++i) {
        char c = duo.at(i);
        int digit = 0;
        if (std::isdigit(c))
            digit = c - '0';
        else if (c == 'x' || c == 'X')
            digit = 10;
        else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E')
            digit = 11;
        else {
            if (stop_on_first_non_digit)
                break;
            else
                continue;
        }
        decValue *= 12;
        decValue += digit;
    }
    std::cout << decValue << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
36
```

Comment: Thank you arty, I appreciate the help.

Comment: @codingStudent702 If my answer is correct and/or useful according to your mind, then don't forget to Accept and/or UpVote it. It is done at the very top of my answer to the left-handside, there is a CheckMark for Accepting answer as correct and Upper Arrow for UpVoting answer as being useful.

Comment: Are you able to advise me as to in if there is a letter before a number, how i could also choose to ignore it. Whenever I google how to ignore a character it comes back with cin.ignore() but I'm not sure how to properly syntax that. I'm not looking for someone to just give me answers I just honestly need the help, even if its "check this website out"", you know anything i can use is appreciated and yes will do.

Comment: @codingStudent702 If you're speaking about same task then in the beginning of my code try to set variable `stop_on_first_non_digit = false` (set to `false`) then any non-digit characters will be ignored. In this task you don't have any `std::cin` at all, so you don't need to ignore its characters. The way you ignore characters in the loop is just by comparing them to possible digits values and if it is non-digit then just do `continue;` in the loop. Loop at my code above, I did exactly what you want, I'm skipping non-digit characters already by doing `continue;`.

Comment: This ignores the fact that OP is using the letters E and X (lowercase included) as their extra digits.

Comment: @sweenish E and X are ignored only if `stop_on_first_non_digit = true` in my code, then code terminates immediately on very first non-digit. It is how OP wanted in his example described in Question, `30-something` should return `36` and nothing else according to OP. But if you set `stop_on_first_non_digit = false` in my then it behaves like You want - inside `30-something` letter `e` is not ignore and counted as digit so that you get final value of `443` instead of `36`.It is up to user of my program to decide whether to use `stop_on_first_non_digit = true` or `stop_on_first_non_digit = false`